# Rails Paperclip Multiple Upload Image Processing Time-Out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, paperclip

I am using AWS EC2 + S3 + Rails + Paperclip to upload multiple image attachments onto a post.  When I do a single large image upload (~5MB), everything works fine.

However, when I do multiple small image uploads (12 images with combined size < 1MB), I get a white screen after upload because of all the post-processing (resizing) that my server has to do.

This happens for all image uploads that exceed about 4-5 images, regardless of the actual size of images.

This is what is happening:

1.) Upload works smoothly, successfully, original size images hit S3 just fine.

2.) Browser hangs for awhile while it is waiting for my server.  My server is meanwhile trying to handling all the post processing for the images just uploaded.

3.) Browser gets sick of waiting and throws a white screen at me.  Just a blank screen.

4.) A refresh of the page works fine, but I notice that the post is not "up" yet, because the images attached to the post are not done processing.

5.) About a minute or two later, post suddenly appears with all images the way they should be.

What are my options in this case?  Is there any way I can make the browser display some kind of loading sign while Paperclip is processing/resizing my images?

Comment: You're running on an EC2 instance?

Comment: Yes, I am, Amazon EC2 Elastic Beanstalk